# Xcode Failed to load profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, iosdeployment

My Xcode suddenly got a weird issue that there's some provisioning profiles I couldn't download or even import them manually. Got an error message all the time.
[image]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Xcode again, and still got the problem. Also, I manually copied the profile into ~Library/Mobile Device/Provisioning Profiles folder, and my Xcode wouldn't recognize it. 
Have anyone seen the issue before? Please don't ask me to delete and re-create the profile as it's a company provisioning profile, and it worked on my colleagues' computer.

Just recognize I was able to load or install all distribution profiles, all development profiles got the issue.

Comment: Does it appear after deleting the derivedData and after project cleaning?

Comment: @George_E_2 it stills happen.

Comment: I'm not sure then, sorry :p

Comment: The error says it's missing the UUID property...first thing I would do if open the profile profile in a text editor and check to see if a UUID is there.

Comment: @Jake: Does it mean device's UUID? Pretty sure it was there, but I don't know why missing device's UUID doesn't allow me to install that profile.

Comment: @LongNV - Provisioning profiles also have a uuid. This uuid is in the file and it is what Xcode uses to identify the profile. This has nothing to do with the devices’ uuids.

Comment: Try installing this on your Mac and see what the profile shows you just to check on the UUID: https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL

Comment: If it is a developer profile (and not a distribution profile), you should see the UDIDs of the devices provisioned when you use the Quick Look on the provisioning profile with ProvisionQL installed. BTW: UUID is for profiles, UDID is for devices.

Comment: @JacobBarnard: I saw both of them there.

Comment: By the way, I have to delete all provisioning profiles on my computer. Delete and reinstall a new Xcode then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few checks I go through when I get anomalous behavior from Xcode with respect to development provisioning profiles.

1. Check to ensure that you have selected the correct Apple ID and correct Team by clicking *Xcode* > *Preferences* > *Accounts* > select the correct Apple ID on the left-hand side of the panel, and select the correct Team at the lower-right hand side of the panel
2. Check to ensure that you have installed the necessary components for Xcode by clicking *Xcode* > *Preferences* > *Components* > ensure the correct *Toolchain* is selected, then > *Check and Install Now*
3. Download the provisioning profile manually from the Apple Developer Portal, then drag-and-drop it onto your Xcode dock icon.
4. Open your project in Xcode and click on the project icon in *Project navigator* > *Build Settings* > scroll down to *Code Signing Identity* > ensure is set to *iOS Developer*
5. While still in *Build Settings*, scroll down to *Provisioning Profile* > ensure the name of the profile you expect is selected or that it is set to *Automatic*
6. Try to build.

If that doesn't work, you can try altering step 4. by doing the following instead:

- Make sure to not select "Automatic" for the "Provisioning Profile" field(s) in Xcode > Build Settings
- Instead, set all "Provisioning Profile" fields specifically to the profile with which you are trying to build
- open the Terminal app
- `cd` to the directory of your Xcode project
- `cd` into your Xcode project, like so: `cd MyProject.xcodeproj/`
- `cd xcuserdata`
- `open project.pbxproj -a TextEdit`
- hold the "command" key and tap "F" on your keyboard
- enter 'PROVISIONING_PROFILE' and press 'return'
- if 1 or more results are found, ensure the value to the right of the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` variable is set to the UUID of the profile you want (i.e. compare to what you see in Quick Look to ensure a match)... if 0 options are found, something else may be wrong with your `xcodeproj` file
- the UUID should be a string (surrounded by double-quotes), e.g. `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "abcdef01-2345-6789-abcd-ef0123456789";`
- save the file with TextEdit and then close TextEdit
- try to build again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the error step 2, when drag profile on XCode to install, it threw above error message.

Comment: Try steps 3 through 5 anyway. Use the alternate bullet points for step 4. What do you get?

Comment: I saw no provisioning profile available to build, then XCode asked I need to import or download it. In case I imported that profile or download it, it would show that error message.

Comment: Don't try to enter the provisioning profile using Xcode GUI. Specify it directly using TextEdit and enter the UUID directly into the `.pbxproj` file. See the unnumbered bullets in my answer. (Use source control to revert if you accidentally corrupt the `pbxproj` such that Xcode won't open the project).

Comment: I also added a new "step 1" - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who also got this issue, I was able to resolve this bug by deleting complete my XCode 9.4.1 and all local provisioning profiles, and update to latest XCode 10.0. After that, I can install and load all profiles as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure installed mobileprovision file is valid, otherwise kindly regenerate the mobileprovision from developer.apple.com site and import it manually in xcodeproject IDE.